# Bash Script Loop for Substitution and Traversal

Tags: bash, shell, unix

So I'm trying to figure out what a question from an old exam means and I'm slightly confused about one or two parts.

```
#!/bin/bash
awk   '{$0 = tolower($0)
      gsub(/[,.?;:#!\(\)]/),"",$0)
      for(a=1;a<=NF;a++)
      b[$a]++}
      END print b[a],a}'
sort -sk2
```

Here is my interpretation:

- target the bash script location
- scan file with awk
- convert string to lower case
- sub all occurrences of symbols with nothing (ie. remove) and overwrite string
- (here is my issue) for every field increment a by 1?
- (again not sure what this is doing) b takes a's number and increments by 1?
- end the for loop and print (b, a)
- sort by size of the second field

I think the last four lines are my main issue. Also is it just me or is there an extra } in that question?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The lone `sort` looks wrong. Is there supposed to be a pipe from `awk` to `sort`?

Comment: @tripleee typed exactly as it was asked so I don't think so

Comment: Then it simply prints the unsorted output from Awk, and then waits for you to type in some other data for it to sort. I'm pretty sure this is a misprint in the original then.

Comment: There's also an opening brace missing after `END` so the script as posted isn't syntactically valid.

Comment: How do you invoke this script? If you don't do something like `myscript < aFile` then awk will have no input to consume, and it will just sit there waiting for input. Your script will "appear frozen".

Comment: @glennjackman the script was from a past exam question and I was just trying to figure it out. It was on the paper as it appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for` loop is weirdly formatted. Here it is again with proper indentation:

```
    for(a=1; a<=NF; a++)
        b[$a]++
```

In other words, we loop over the field positions; for each, the count in the associative array `b` is incremented. So if the current input line is

```
foo bar poo bar baz
```

the script will do

```
b["foo"]++  # a is 1; $a is $1
b["bar"]++
b["poo"]++
b["bar"]++
b["baz"]++
```

So now `b` contains a set of tokens as keys, and the number of times each occurred as their respective values. In other words, this collects word counts for each word in the input.

The case folding and removal of punctuation normalizes the input so that

```
Word word word, word!
```

will count as four occurrences of "word", rather than one each for the capitalized version, the undecorated normal form, and the ones with punctuation attached at the end. It slightly distorts e.g. words which should properly be capitalized, and conflates into homographs words which are differentiated only by capitalization (such as *china* porcelain vs *China* the country.)

The `END` block is executed only when all input lines have been consumed, and thus `b` is fully loaded with all input words from all input lines, with their final counts. (Though here, there is no valid `END` block actually, because the opening brace after `END` is missing; this is a fatal syntax error. There isn't one closing brace too many, there's one non-optional opening brace missing.)

Comment: I agree it is not written well, but as far as I know indentation is not strictly required in Bash (but always a good idea).

So basically the entire script is converting to lower case, clearing any symbols and counting the words?

Any idea what the sort is doing as I don't understand `-k`?

Comment: Like [its manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) will readily reveal, the `-k` option selects which field to sort on. If we were sorting the output from Awk, the second field it prints for each key in the `END` block is the key itself, so you'd get an alphabetically sorted list of the words, each prepended by its count.

Comment: Indeed, Bash and Awk don't care about indentation, but the most important reader - the human, you - was misled.